# Change the color of border-bottom of menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am working on this website https://fortlauderdaleflorida.realestate/
I want to change the color of border-bottom of the top menu. It appears on hover. It is currently yellow and I want to change it to blue. I have written this CSS for this but it doesn't works

```
.elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item:hover{
    color: green;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Color and text-decoration property is working but border-bottom is not working. Please tell me how can I do that.

Comment: You need to target `.elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:before, .elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:after` for the border-bottom since the yellow underline is a after pseudo-element. https://prnt.sc/ovejts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should write

```css
.elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:before, .elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item:after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Because the yellow line isn't `<a>`'s but `<a>::after`'s.

Answer (score 1):

you should add in your css

**css**

```
.elementor-2992 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1b362db .elementor-nav-menu--main:not(.e--pointer-framed) .elementor-item::after {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it also worked. I accept the other answer because it came first but I have up voted your answer because it also help me.